# linq EF array.All(value)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this table:
**tblAdFields**

```
id (bigint)  
adId (bigint)  
listId (bigint)  
listFieldValue (bigint)
```

---

**BEFORE NOW**

---

before now i had a list:

```
List<long> lstFldVal = new List<long>();  
lstFldVal.Add(100);  
lstFldVal.Add(120);  
lstFldVal.Add(150);  
lstFldVal.Add(170);
```

**and get all ad that match all my list by this query:**

```
var qAd =
from adFieldVal in cwContext.tblAdFields
group adField by adField.adId into adAdFields
where lstFldVal.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.fieldId).Contains(i))
```

---

**BUT NOW**

---

but now i need check my table with array or list of class:
here is my new lstFldValNew

```
var lstFldValNew= new int?[][] ////listId, rangeTypeId(equal, more, less, between), from, to
{ 
new int?[] { 1, 1, 100, null }, 
new int?[] { 2, 2, 125, null }, 
new int?[] { 3, 3, null, 175 }, 
new int?[] { 4, 4, 125, 175 }
};
```

I want to know which adId has listFieldValue where:

1) (listId == 1)&&(listFieldValue == 100)
**and**
2) (listId == 2)&&(listFieldValue > 125)
**and**
3) (listId == 3)&&(listFieldValue < 175)
**and**
4) ((listId == 4)&&(listFieldValue > 130)&&(listFieldValue < 180))

i started by this line in where, but get error:
where lstFldValNew.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listId).Contains(i.listId))
and didn't continue!

Comment: What is your question, and what is the actual error type and message you are getting?

Comment: in fact when i have 1D array everything is ok, but when i have multidimensional array i can do.

Comment: error: only primitive types ('such as int32 string and guid') are supported in this context site

Comment: Mohammad - could you please update your post to say the error and the line (if any) that it is being thrown on?

Comment: Also, please update your post with all of the information about your table, i.e. mark any table columns that are nullable, etc.

Comment: @ Zachary Kniebel thank you for replay. table is correct and complete, please consider when i use (1D array).all(....), every thing is ok. but when i use (multi array).all(...) i get error,

Comment: @ Zachary Kniebel i mean when i just check listfieldvalue in a singe dimension array everything is ok, but now i need to check listId and listfieldvalue, that's my problem.